# Video download from url on android

Tags: android, video, download

In my android app I must download some video from url. For this I use this function :

```
private void saveVideoToSDcard(String video) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(video);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String name = video.substring(video.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        System.out.println("image download beginning: " + name);

        // Open a connection to that URL
        ucon = url.openConnection();

        // this timeout affects how long it takes for the app to realize there's
        // a connection problem
        ucon.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
        ucon.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

        // Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
        // uses 3KB download buffer
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Downloads/"
                        + name);
        byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

        // Read bytes (and store them) until there is nothing more to read(-1)
        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
        }

        // clean up
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inStream.close();

        System.out.println("download completed in "
                + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");

    }
```

and I call this function on onCreate() method :

```
for (int j = 0; j < jArray.length(); j++) {
            if (target[j].endsWith(".mp4")) {
                System.out.println("video de downloadat");
                String name = target[j]
                        .substring(target[j].lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                try {

                    saveVideoToSDcard(target[j]);
                    target[j] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Downloads/" + name;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

where `target[]` is an array that contains the video's url.

The videos are downloaded on `Downloads` folder, but I have this problem : for a moment I downloaded 2 videos : first video has duration 1:17 and second video has duration 2:38. If I open first video it plays for 10 seconds and after that it close unexpectedly. The second video doesn't have this problem, it works fine. Do you have any idea why I have this problem ?

Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everytime the same video has a problem?

Comment: yes, the same video. Every time I run the app the videos are again download, and first video never worked fine

Comment: What about if you interchanged the download number? first download the second video with 2.38 length then second? then what happen?

Comment: Still the same problem, second video works ok and first video not. When I open first video I get ERROR/MoviePlayer(3087): onDestroy() on LogCat

Comment: Means now this time the video with 2:38 duration is crashed. And video with 1:17 duration work well. right?

Comment: no. It is strange but it is inversely: the video with 2:38 duration works well and the other one with 1:17 duration crashed. so it looks that the duration is not relevant.

Comment: what is the full url of video with 1:17 duration?

Comment: oooohhhhh...now I opened the video on browser and I see that video is working for about 10 seconds like on device. So, the video is the problem. Sorry for this :). Thanks anywhy for tring to help me.